# Two displays (screens) on device. How to work?

Tags: flutter, dart, screen, display, multiscreen

How to work with second display (screen) in Flutter?
A device connected to another screen via an HDMI or Wireless.
Support to run on two screens.

My question like as [Which Flutter plugin or feature can utilize an external iOS/Android display showing separate content from the main display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955193/which-flutter-plugin-or-feature-can-utilize-an-external-ios-android-display-show)